# Setting vim options only for files in a certain directory tree?

Tags: vim, vimrc

There is a programming project I work on where everyone else uses a tabsize of 4, so I find it most straightforward to `set tabstop=4` in my `~/.vimrc`. However, I'd rather not have this affect every file I edit - just those for this project - let's say every file in a certain directory (and its subdirectories).

Is there a way I can easily conditionally set variables based on the directory prefix of the file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889602/multiple-vim-configurations

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## local / project-specific configuration

If it's okay to configure the specific commands / local exceptions centrally, you can put such autocmds into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/dir/* setlocal ts=4 sw=4
```

It is important to use `:setlocal` instead of `:set`, and likewise `:map <buffer> ...` and `:command! -buffer ...`.

On the other hand, if you want the specific configuration stored with the project (and don't want to embed this in all files via *modelines*), you have the following two options:

### Local config with built-in functionality

If you always start Vim from the project root directory, the built-in

```
:set exrc
```

enables the reading of a `.vimrc` file from the current directory. You can place the `:set ts=4 sw=4` commands in there.

### Local config through plugin

Otherwise, you need the help of a plugin; there are several on vim.org; I can recommend the [localrc plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393) (especially with [my own enhancements](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-localrc/tree/enhancements)), which even allows local filetype-specific configuration.

<sup>Note that reading configuration from the file system has security implications; you may want to `:set secure`.</sup>

Comment: The third solution (the plugin) is excellent, and exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I'm trying to avoid putting the config centrally, so you're right that the first is not ideal. Thanks for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Great! I also use the localrc plugin; it's truly useful.

Comment: In case anyone else runs into an issue of the `autocmd` method not working, make sure you don't have any symlinks in your path -- I had to put the full path with no symlinks before it would work for me (on OS X 10.9)

Comment: The solution of using `set exrc` and a `.vimrc` file is easy to implement and I find it very useful. I would like to understand why would someone use a plugin for this? Are there better solutions in 2023?

Comment: @Unix To me the biggest downside of `exrc` is that you need to start Vim from the project directory. I share a single GVIM instance across projects, and for that a local vimrc plugin becomes indispensable.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you, @IngoKarkat!

Answer (score 4):

You can configure vim to read further commands using the `source` (so) command.
Add this to your `~/.vimrc` - it searches the current directory and if .vimrc_proj file not found there searches for .vimrc_proj in the parent directory.

```
if filereadable(".vimrc_proj")
    so .vimrc_proj
else
    if filereadable("../.vimrc_proj")
         so .vimrc_proj
    endif
endif
```

Then add any custom commands in `.vimrc_proj` config files to suit your projects.

Comment: I think that only works if I'm in the project's directory when I open the file, right? This doesn't handle where the current directory is something completely different.

Comment: Correct, that is a limitation

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plugin for Vim to solve the problem in a more general way by trying to detect the indention.

The plugin of choice for me is [DetectIndent](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1171). It took some time for me to test all the forks of the plugin to find one that suits my needs. The original one was really close but not quite so I made my [own fork](https://github.com/ypid/detectindent).

For debugging it is very helpful to `:set verbose=1` and run the plugin again with `:DetectIndent`

Comment: I think you may have put this answer on the wrong question? It doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier This answer is perfectly in place, it just presents different attitude to the problem. Instead of setting tab size for specific files you can use a plugin to detect correct tab size for each file.

Comment: @gronostaj my question wasn't really about setting tab sizes, it was about per-directory-tree configuration - the tab size was just an example. But I see what you were getting at now, and it is a useful tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution which was not mentioned yet is to go one level above and implement project-specific shell scripts to fire up your vim environment.

This allows vim-specific settings to be passed using the `-S` command-line option. The advantage is that it also allows configuring other aspects of the environment, such as the terminal or cscope settings.

For example, let's say I have a C++ project called `foo`, for which I want to load vim settings of the file `~/.vim/projects/foo.vim`. I also want to set up a cscope index and launch a terminal window if the command is invoked from some quick launch tool or desktop shortcut. To open up my environment, I have the following script, called `vim-foo`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to setup the VIM development environment of my "foo" project
# Includes building ctags and cscope databases.

VIM_CONFIG=$HOME/.vim/projects/foo.vim
BASE_DIR=$HOME/work/foo

function setup_cscope()
{
    CSCOPE_FILES=$BASE_DIR/cscope.files

    created_files=false

    # check if global cscope.files exist
    if [ ! -f $CSCOPE_FILES ]; then
        echo "Creating cscope.files"
        find $BASE_DIR/src -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' >> $CSCOPE_FILES
        created_files=true
    fi

    # create cscope database
    if [ $created_files ] || \ 
        [ ! -f $BASE_DIR/cscope.in.out ] || \
        [ ! -f $BASE_DIR/cscope.po.out ] || \
        [ ! -f $BASE_DIR/cscope.out ]; then
            echo "Creating cscope database"
            cscope -b -q -i $CSCOPE_FILES
            for f in in.out po.out out; do
                mv cscope.$f $BASE_DIR/
            done
    fi

    export CSCOPE_DB=$BASE_DIR/cscope.out
}

# setup everything and finally launch vim
setup_cscope
cd $BASE_DIR
if [[ $TERM == "rxvt-unicode" ]]; then
    vim -S $VIM_CONFIG
else
    urxvt -e vim -S $VIM_CONFIG
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim supports [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) so you can put a `.editorconfig` file in that directory with something like:

```
# 4 space indentation for all .c files.
[*.c]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
```

If you commit this to the project's version control then everybody can share it and it will work with their editors too.